# Scala Regex match in between and after words in a string

Tags: regex, scala, regex-negation

Scala is giving me a hard time to do a regex which works easily on a "text editor" I used to test.

These are the rules for the string match:

For the word "dek affect"

1. Any symbol in-between the words are OK except for "."
2. Any numeric values not allowed in between the words
3. Any alphabet after the last word other than "s" is not allowed.

Following are some example cases:
1. "**dek affects** in the forest" => OK .
2. "my **dek affect** is here" => OK .
3. "**dek?affect#**" => OK .
4. "**dek1affect**" => NOT OK .
5. "**dek. affect**", => NOT OK .
6. "**dek affecting**" => NOT OK .

I have tried the code which works fine for 1, 3, 5 and 6 from the sample cases except for 2 and 4.

```
// For example case 2
"dek affect" matches ".*dek[^\\.]affect[^a-r t-z].*"
// output: false

// For example case 4
"dek1affect" matches ".*dek[^\\.]affect[^a-r t-z].*"
// output: false
```

I expect the output to be "true" but its showing "false". The negation is expecting "s" at the end but how do I make it optional?

Another question is how do I make the regex dynamic, like what if I have 3 or more words in the string, any easy way of doing regex in between the words in **Scala**?

Comment: You do realize that "connect" and "affect" are different words, don't you?

Comment: that was a typo! fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets pretty close. At least it passes all your tests.

```
val word1 = "dek"
val word2 = "affect"

Seq("dek affects in the forest" //=> OK .
   ,"my dek affect is here"     //=> OK .
   ,"dek?affect#"               //=> OK .
   ,"dek1affect"                //=> NOT OK .
   ,"dek. affect"               //=> NOT OK .
   ,"dek affecting"             //=> NOT OK .
).map(_ matches s".*$word1[^.\\w]$word2[s\\W].*")
//res0: Seq[Boolean] = List(true, true, true, false, false, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way..

Please note that there is inconsistency in your logic.. you say `Any character after the last word other than "s" is not allowed.` but you allow `dek?affect#` to be matched. Please review

```
scala> lst
res53: Seq[String] = List(dek affects in the forest, my dek affect is here, dek?affect#, dek1affect, dek. affect, dek affecting)

scala>  lst.map( _ matches ".*dek.(?<!=\\d)(?<!=\\.)(affect(s|#|.(?<= ))).*" )
res54: Seq[Boolean] = List(true, true, true, false, false, false)

scala>
```

**EDIT:**

```
scala> lst.map( _ matches """.*dek.(?<!=\d|\.)affect.(?<=[^a-rt-z]).*""" )
res68: Seq[Boolean] = List(true, true, true, false, false, false)

scala>
```

Comment: I meant alphabet, changed it to alphabet instead of saying character